# Involution in a commutative unital real C* algebra

Tags: c-star-algebras, gelfand-duality

It follows immediately from Gelfand duality that the involution in a commutative unital real C* algebra is the identity.  Is there a direct proof from the axioms of C* algebras?

Answer (score 3):

Is that really true? Consider the set of real $2\times 2$ matrices of the form $\left[\begin{matrix}a&b\cr -b&a\end{matrix}\right]$. That's a commutative unital algebra which is stable under transpose, so a real C*-algebra according to the definition I know, but the involution is the transpose operation, which is not the identity here.